# How do I update subscriber attribute in AMPScript while sending email

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I've included a personalization AMPScript code in an email template.

For each subscriber, I'm calling several webservices (not ET web API), with subscriber attributes as input. I would like to cache some data, not to call them again next time, and then I'm planning to save the interesting output of the web services as Subscriber attributes.

How could I do that?

I've looked at `CreateObject("Attribute")`, `SetObjectProperty`, but I don't know how to get the current Subscriber object.

regards

Answer (score 2):

The solution you need to use is not elegant at all, but it works.  I've spoken with people who say this really is the way to do this.

1. Create a Data Extension with the SubscriberKey as the PK column, and each of the attributes you want to modify as their own column.
2. In the email, use [UpdateDE](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/data_extension_ampscript_functions/#UpdateDE)  to put those values in the Data Extension.
3. Create a Data Extension Extract under Data Extract Activities to export that Data Extension to a file.
4. Import that created file via an Import Activity into the All Subscribers list.

You could run this as part of an automation in Automation Studio if you wish.

Good luck!

Comment: I've added just  `SET @subscriber = CreateObject( "subscriber" )  SetObjectProperty( @subscriber, "SubscriberKey", _SubscriberKey )`  to a working template, but now, the sending fails.  
  
I've also tried `SetObjectProperty( @subscriber, "SubscriberKey", subscriberid)` , but I still have an error when sending

Comment: in [AMP script documentation](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/api_ampscript_functions/), I read _Create your AMPscript using the functions below and place them in the content areas of landing pages. These functions do not work in **emails at the time of send** and will cause your send to **error** out._

Comment: Thank, I'll try your solution. By the way, I don't need the steps 3 and 4, I think, as those data will not be used elsewhere - they can stay in a DataExtension table.  For your information, in that other [page](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/using_ampscript_with_the_web_service_api/), they say _Please contact your ExactTarget representative if you wish to enable your account to use the web service API._ . I'll try that too.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t call create function while sending email. You may do it via ssjs script prior to sending email.