# Change Subscriber Email Address via AMPScript in Email

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, send-email

We have a task to set specific email address for subscriber (recipient' email address) during email sending based on some criteria in sendable Data Extension. 
We tried to use AMPScript functions like `CreateObject( "Subscriber" )` but it causes the error:

> "CreateObject Function is not valid in content. This function is only
>   allowed in non sendable content."

What other possible solutions to send email to specific address defined in AMPScript exist? Is it possible at all?

Comment: do you want to change the subscriber EmailAddress in All Subscriber list?

Comment: Can you explain why the subscriber's email address needs to be changed "during email sending"? If the information is available before the send, as @PalashRai suggests, can All Subscribers be updated instead? Check out these similar questions: [update subscriber attribute in ampscript](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/56512/how-do-i-update-subscriber-attribute-in-ampscript-while-sending-email) and [update profile attributes](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/162678/automatically-update-profile-attributes)

Comment: @Pa Right, Ideally we need to implement one MC Contact with multiple email addresses. So, if it is possible to change EmailAddress for Subscriber, it might resolve this.

Comment: @CameronRobert We have to send email to different addresses based on subscriber attribute. I don't believe that this is possible based on one MC Contact. I just want to be 100% sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you [read this article here](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_update_insert_and_delete_calls__processing_during_sends/). Basically, AMPscript is evaluated as the last thing during the send, so you wouldn't be able to update the email address during send.